# Request for Existing Source Code on Defect Trend App

Tags: rally

I started modifying/developing Rally apps about a week ago using the existing Rally apps provided on the Github repository so far. However, for one of my final tasks I've been asked to recreate a tailored Defect Trend Report App and unfortunately, the source code is not available for the App. I tried to start from scratch but I've ran into numerous errors and am a bit overwhelmed.

I was wondering if anyone had the src code for the app or knew of a way to extract the src code from the existing app. Of course if there is custom code that an individual has worked on that could also help me progress in this process and wouldn't mind sharing it, that'd also help a ton.

I saw that there were a few snippets that could be used from the Hackathon repo, but they're not quite on the mark of what I want to do with the app. I'm just trying to have the existing app filtered by delivery versions (currently filtered by iteration/release).

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks fellas!

Comment: is this one anything like it [link](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/lookback-defect-trend-example)

Comment: Good find! Hadn't found that repo before. I was looking for something more specific to the Release Defect Trend App, but this may be a good starting point. Still interested in other solutions if anyone knows of any.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of a 'bare metal' chart app in the App SDK 2.0 docs. It should give you the basics on how to do a chart.To get to it, go to the help pages (click on avatar in top right corner) and search for "Rally App SDK"

After that, you need to work out how to select defects from the various releases and do a count of each. There are two ways to do this:

1. Get all defects in the project you are in (don't forget whether you need to scope down to child projects too) and then do something like _.uniq() on the release field to find the list of releases (or do another request to get all the releases into a different store and use that for names and a count).
2. Get the releases and then for each release request the related defects.

If you do ask for child projects, you will need to handle all the scenarios of different releases for different projects - can get complicated!

#1 is effectively one big fetch, #2 may be many smaller ones.

You may want to decide whether to count all defects, sum the estimates, ignore those not finished, etc., etc.

Comment: BTW, if you want to sort by a custom field, that is just as easy, but you may need to use method 1 and do _uniq on the custom field (delivery?)

Comment: How do I go about using this custom code with rally-app-builder? It has HTML tags and seems to be the embedded code that I would install into a 'Custom HTML' app.